# What does $\|$ mean in this definition of the total derivative of a function?

Tags: calculus, notation

What does $\|$ mean in this definition of total derivative? picture:

[image]

Comment: It is the norm of a vector function.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [the full definition you are referring to on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#The_total_derivative_as_a_linear_map):

> [image]

The symbols $x$ and $p$ denote elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the expressions
$$f(x),\qquad f(p),\qquad \mathrm{d}f_p(x-p)$$
all denote elements of $\mathbb{R}^m$. In the numerator,
$\|\cdots\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$, and in the denominator, it denotes the Euclidean norm of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (it is technically an abuse of notation to have the same symbol for both purposes, but it is clear enough).

Recall [the definition of the Euclidean norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm):

> [image]

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure about that, it's much more clear now

Comment: Glad I could help!